# Does Facebook's Conversion API Gateway store user PII? How long?

Tags: facebook, api, conversions, privacy-policy

If we implement Facebook's Conversion API Gateway through Amazon AWS, Does this implementation store user PII? Does it store it 180 days? Could anyone tell me more about the retention policy?